# Can a wireless repeater have more devices attached than the wireless router capacity?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, repeater

My current wireless router only accepts a handful of devices simultaneously but I have more than 30 smart devices around the house. I wanted to buy a couple of wireless repeaters for each room and hook similar devices to each. I know these devices will indirectly attach to the main router and be similarly  named as the repeater. Can a wireless repeater have more devices attached and functional than the my current wireless routers capacity?

Ps:
The router is a mobile router, providing internet with dynamic IP addressing as a local LAN network and only accepts 8 devices at a time. The repeaters that I am looking at accept 20 devices each. Smart devices include computers, printers, mobiles and tablets, TVs and game consoles, several smart light bulbs, several smart plugs and power boards, several window sensors, several IP cameras, speakers, cast and streaming devices, wifi switches, temperature, pressure, humidity, IR, movement and other wifi sensors and smart kitchen appliances... The question is, can I hook like 46 devices to the repeaters and the router when the router only accepts 8?

Comment: What makes you say your router “only accepts a handful of devices simultaneously”?

Comment: Assuming you arr actually talking about wireless repeaters and routers (based on your tags) even a good router could likely handle it. What kind of smart devices are those you got? What is the actual router you got? What repeaters are you considering?

Comment: Edited the post and added the requested information. Thank you.